# .net iis7 website cookies stop working overnight

Tags: .net, cookies, iis-7, umbraco

I have a .net 4, umbraco 4.7, website running on iis7.

The website uses cookies to track referrers to the website.  These cookies work for a period of time, then they stop working after many hours.  The cookies just stop being picked up by .net.

Bumping the web.config or recycling the application pool re-enables the picking up of cookie's.

Here is the code that is used to check for cookies and set the cookie.

```
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["partner"] == null)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies["partner"]["partnerId"] = this.PartnerName;
```

Please help with any ideas or suggestions for what could be causing this behavior.

Cheers,

Paul

Comment: What duration are you setting the expriation for?

Comment: I am setting the cookie's expiry to 1 day in the future. `HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies["partner"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(24);`

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the domain explicitly in the web.config. Content should be changed from:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
            <forms name="yourAuthCookie" loginUrl="login.aspx" protection="All" path="/" />
        </authentication>
```

... to something more like this ...

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
            <forms name="yourAuthCookie" domain="stackoverflow.com" loginUrl="login.aspx" protection="All" path="/" />
        </authentication>
```

**NOTE**: It is recommmended that you do NOT use the www prefix (www.stackoverflow.com) because if you do, then a different cookie will be given to users visiting http://stackoverflow.com compared with those visiting on http://www.stackoverflow.com

Comment: You can also set the cookie usage and cookie expiration in the same web.config location by setting the "forms" tag's attributes:  cookieless="UseCookies" timeout="1440" slidingExpiration="true"

Comment: Thank you for the answer CSharpForEverMore, however I have gotten around my problem by recycling the app pool early in the morning, around 3am.  I hope your answer helps someone, Cheers